# Android: Back click exists from app when using YouTube API

Tags: java, android, android-activity, youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube API for android. Below is the code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private boolean isFullScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
//        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            this.player = player;
            this.player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
           // player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);

            player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                    isFullScreen = true;
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Back pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(isFullScreen)
        {
            player.setFullscreen(false);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/youtube_view"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the `Full Screen` is visible and if the user clicked back, I want my `Activity` to be displayed. Instead what is happening now is the back button exists from the app.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
I Identified the error, inside the `setOnFullScreenListener` it was never identified the app is in Full screen, even though it is. I tried forcing the boolean into true, but it ended up crashing saying the `player` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but in your `onFullScreen()` override method, you have set

```
isFullScreen = true;
```

Rather, use

```
isFullScreen = b;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just remove the `if` condition in `onInitializationSuccess`. Below is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private boolean isFullScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
//        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            this.player = player;
            this.player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo

           // player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);

            this.player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                    isFullScreen = b;
                }
            });


    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if(isFullScreen)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Full Screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            player.setFullscreen(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not Full Screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```